# How to get ezComponents ConsoleTools installed

Tags: php, zeta-components

Since PEAR attempts to get ConsoleTools from "components.ez.no", which is not available anymore, how does satisfy that dependency for "phpcpd" installation?

Comment: [root@localhost src]# pear install phpunit/phpcpd
Unknown remote channel: components.ez.no
phpunit/phpcpd requires package "channel://components.ez.no/ConsoleTools" (version >= 1.6)
No valid packages found
install failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pear release for the moment. You can [install from svn](https://cwiki.apache.org/ZETACOMP/tutorial-installation.html).

You can also try to install phpcd from github, it might not depend on ConsoleTools: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcpd/blob/master/README.markdown

Answer (score 2):

Installing from SVN was a 500mb download. If you don't need the entire package, these commands will work, and are much smaller.

I was receiving this when trying to install:

```
$ pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator 
Unknown remote channel: components.ez.no
phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator requires package "channel://components.ez.no/ConsoleTools (version >= 1.6)
No valid packages found
install failed
```

All you need to do is run this:

```
$ pecl channel-discover components.ez.no
```

You should receive these success messages... 
    Adding Channel "components.ez.no" succeeded
    Discovery of channel "components.ez.no" succeeded

Now the command will work correctly...

```
$ pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator
```

My output was:

```
downloading PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator-1.2.0.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator-1.2.0.tgz (11,210 bytes)
.....done: 11,210 bytes
downloading ConsoleTools-1.6.1.tgz ...
Starting to download ConsoleTools-1.6.1.tgz (869,994 bytes)
...done: 869,994 bytes
downloading Base-1.8.tgz ...
Starting to download Base-1.8.tgz (236,357 bytes)
...done: 236,357 bytes
install ok: channel://components.ez.no/Base-1.8
install ok: channel://components.ez.no/ConsoleTools-1.6.1
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator-1.2.0
```